# Is this causing a mutation and is it possible to rewrite this to be mutationless?

Tags: javascript

```
function toggleFunction(key, value) {
  if (package[key]) {
    const updatedPackage = package[key].includes(value) ?
    package[key].filter(v => v !== value) :
    [...package[key], value]
    callSetUseState(key, updatedPackage)
  }
}
```

I am thinking that package[key].filter is a mutation since it's creating a new object inside the reference of an old object. I am wondering if just recreating package with const newPackage = {... package}, could solve this issue or not. I am not sure if copying the object will make sure the mutation doesn't cause a side effect beyond it and if there's a way to rewrite this without causing any mutation.

Comment: Nope, looks fine - although `callSetUseState` will have to be properly implemented too

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*inside the reference of an old object*"

Comment: JS Array `filter()` method creates a new array and doesn't modify the original one (unless the function you pass does it).

Comment: Is `callSetUseState` something to do with React Hooks? Adding the tag for that library would be helpful to guide the answers.

Comment: It kind of depends on what the element type of `package[key]` is and how you use it afterwards. If `package[key]`'s elements are `object` type, you will be able to mutate the elements if you modify them afterwards. But either way, `package` and `package[key]` are not mutated.

Comment: let [bundle, callSetUseState] = useState({
        ...
}); I thought package[key].filter was the same as doing package[key] = array(), which is a mutation.

Comment: is callSetUseState synchronous or async, what do you do if you need to call 2 callSetUseState in a row? I am thinking the issue is that two of them are done one after another really fast.